# Google Cloud Storage and BigQuery

Tags: google-app-engine, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I'm performing the exercise at the following link:
https://developers.google.com/bigquery/loading-data-into-bigquery
But I stopped at step 2 Loading data from Google Cloud Storage, that is Create a load job pointing to the source data in Google Cloud Storage. The source URIs must be fully-qualified, in the format gs:///. How do I create a job?

Answer (score 0):

The (python) code to create a load job is in the example right under the text that you referenced. (note that there is a doc bug... there should be only two slashes after `gs:`).

Comment: Where do I create job files? I have to create a new project? I spegate in more detail? (using java you can create the job?) thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. There are no job files. Jobs are json objects that get posted to the bigquery service. Do you not have a project?

Comment: no. I do not have a project! I want to load a dataset of BigQuery. The creation of the job as I do?

Comment: [step 1: do you have a .csv file?] [step 2: have you uploaded it to google cloud storage] [step 3: use https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/ to create a dataset and point it to the uploaded file]